# Qual a maneira correta de recuperar um ArrayList<Long> do cloud firestore?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firestore, cloud

Estou usando o seguinte código para tentar recuperar um ArrayList do firestore:

```
List<Long> longs = (List<Long>) task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i.get()).get("longsArray");
```

Entretanto não estou certo de estar fazendo isto da maneira correta, pois estou recendo o seguinte erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.exemplifique.project, PID: 14521
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o retorno da API já é especificado, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
List<Long> longs = (ArrayList<Long>) task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i.get()).get("longsArray");
```